# Trouble with MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: django, windows

I've finished a beginner's tutorial on django-project and now I am trying to go further.
So, I want to add an ability to add images to polls. To do that, I need to add 'django.template.context_processors.media' to context_prosessors and create MEDIA_ROOT. 
So i did

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
print(str(BASE_DIR))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, MEDIA_URL)
print(str(MEDIA_ROOT))
```

But when I run the django-server I see the following results of the print functions:

[image: print result]

What am I doing wrong? And why do I see the results of the print functions twice?

Comment: Please don't post code in images.  You are much more likely to get an answer if you post code that is copyable

Comment: The code is copyable. I posted an image of the console output, I don't think anyone will need it, it's just a result of two print functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

To:

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

---

Study this example to know what is happening:

```
import os

print(os.path.join('a', 'b/'))    # prints "a/b/"
print(os.path.join('a', '/b/'))   # prints "/b/"
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but the console output said "The MEDIA_URL setting must end with a slash.", so I changed '/media/' to 'media/' and it worked. It works but the result of the second print function is still pretty strange. The slash at the end faces to the oppsite direction like so D:\Other\Prog\DjangoLearning\first_mysite\media/. I supporse it's because I am on Windows

Comment: `I suppose it's because I am on Windows`: Right!