# Showing user-uploaded images in a template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have added all the necessary code to settins.py (MEDIA_URL, MEDIA_ROOT and django.template.context_processors.media). 
I've also created a model for an image

```
class Image(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to="polls/")
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 60, default = "Unknown")
```

So when I upload a picture via the admin panel django saves it to mysite/media/polls
How do I access the images from a template now? I tried a lot and the closed attempt seems to be

```
{% if question.image_set %}
  {% for image in question.image_set.all %}
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image.file }}">
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The result of this template is something like `<img src="media/polls/rabstol_net_china_04_1600x1200.jpg">`
the path seems to be correct, but the image doesn't appear. I suppose it's because the result is a relative path, but I don't know how to make it an absolute.
Settings:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, MEDIA_URL)
...
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  {% for image in question.image_set.all %}
    {% if image.file %}
    <img src="{{ image.file.url }}">
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: The resulting html code still looks like <img src="media/polls/rabstol_net_china_04_1600x1200.jpg">, but the image doesn't appear...

Comment: if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT),     add these lines to main url if it is not there

Comment: Still the same result. BTW, static files work even without those lines.

Comment: media files will work only with that lines, it should be added after the url patterns and debug should be true

Comment: The debug is true and your code is added after urlpatterns

Comment: post your settings, the media cofig part please

Comment: Added to the post. You know, i was trying to fix it and I just created an image directory near the templates and put a picture in it. Then I just hardcoded <img src="images.4.jpg"> in one of the templates and it still doesn't show this picture. So maybe the problem isn't in media?

Comment: Change media url to "/media/"

Comment: I tried that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910354/trouble-with-media-root